# okhttp3 throwing java.io.IOException: shutdown

Tags: java, exception, okhttp

I have configured `http client connect: 2sec, read:10sec timeout`.
But in somecases HTTP client is taking `more than 12 sec to throw an exception max time>900sec`.

```
    Exception:
java.io.IOException: shutdown
        at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedConnection.newStream(FramedConnection.java:259) ~
        at okhttp3.internal.framed.FramedConnection.newStream(FramedConnection.java:245) ~
        at okhttp3.internal.http.Http2xStream.writeRequestHeaders(Http2xStream.java:135) ~
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:748) ~
```

looks like it's not because of readtimeout because in this this should have thrown HTTPclient readtimeout exception and after 10sec itself.

Comment: OkHttp version?

Comment: same thing. okhttp 2.7.0. It throws it only for the first time on app start, futher requests go fine